# Question about another post. Dedekind Cuts

Tags: real-analysis

[Sum of two Dedekind cuts is well-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/sum-of-two-dedekind-cuts-is-well-defined)

In that we take the cut $A|B$ with $\sqrt2$ and $A'|B'$ with $-\sqrt2$

But I'm not seeing how $A+A' = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x<0 \}$ and $B+B' = \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x\geq0 \}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0):

Note: The point of that question is that $B+B'$ is *not* equal to $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\colon x\geq0\}$, but instead, it is equal to $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\colon x>0\}$.

I'll assume the definition of the sum $S+T$ for two sets $S$ and $T$ is given by $S+T=\{s+t\colon s\in S,t\in T\}$.

Given $B=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}\colon x\geq\sqrt2\}$ and $B'=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\colon x\geq-\sqrt2\}$, for any $x\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$ we have that $\sqrt2+x$ is a *real* number strictly larger than $\sqrt2$, so there must be a *rational* number $s\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $\sqrt2<s<\sqrt2+x$, so $s\in B$. And now $t=x-s\in\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies $t=x-s>x-(\sqrt{2}+x)=-\sqrt2$, so $t\in B'$. Hence, $s+t=x\in B+B'$, so $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\colon x>0\}\subseteq B+B'$.

The other inclusion is much simpler: For $s\in B$ and $t\in B'$ we have $s>\sqrt2$ and $t>-\sqrt2$ so $s+t>\sqrt2+-\sqrt2=0$ so $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}\colon x>0\}\supseteq B+B'$.

Similarly for $A+A'$.

The tricky part is the existence of the rational number $s$ with $\sqrt2<s<\sqrt2+x$.